# Import tweets from specific user and exclude retweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm in the middle of a project and im trying to import some tweets from sepecific twitter users(in python). I got stuck and i cant find any way to exclude retweets from my final list in which tweets will be stored.Below you can find my code. Any help ?

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


name1 = ""

tweetCount1 = 5

results1 = api.user_timeline(
    id=name1, count=tweetCount1, tweet_mode='extended',)

a = []

for tweet in results1:
    a.append(tweet.full_text)
print(a)
print(type(a))
```

Comment: I don't know tweepy well but I would assume name1 = "" is NOT correct. Did you delete the user just for this post or is your code like that?

Also you are initializing api twice, that shouldn't break it but just isn't needed.

Comment: Yes i deleted user just for this post and yes its my fault i just copied twice this part of code.